# Android - progress dialog for an "syncronous" task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When my app is used for the first time i am performing some data setup etc that takes a "random" time to complete, whilst this is going on i'm showing a progress dialog to the user telling them whats going on and presenting a spinning wheel, this is all done via an async task as the many docs and guides say is the only way to go about using a progress dialog.

but my problem is i need everything else in my app to "wait" for the data setup to be finished before it goes about its business but still keep the handy dialog telling the user whats going on, im struggling to find how to go about this.

if anyone has any ideas that be great.

Comment: on post execute progress.cancel();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Threads for doing data setup , and handlers for implementation after the work in thread is over..

See Below

```
ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please Wait..", "Data Setup in       Progress..", false, true);
pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
Thread tDataSetup = new Thread(
new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        //Insert the data setup code here.. 
    if(dataSetupDone)
        handlerDataSetup.sendEmptyMessage(OPERATION_COMPLETED);
    else
        handlerDataSetup.sendEmptyMessage(OPERATION_NOT_COMPLETED);
    }
});
tDataSetup.start();

private Handler handlerDataSetup = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        if(pd.isShowing())
        {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        if(msg.what == OPERATION_COMPLETED)
            //Code after the data Setup done , to be implemented here..
        else if(msg.what == OPERATION_NOT_COMPLETED)
            //Code if data setup fails..
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
 ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
 progress.setTitle("Loading");
 progress.setMessage("Wait while loading...");
 progress.show();
 // your vairiable time stuff here
 // To dismiss the dialog
 progress.dismiss();
```

if you need to update your progress dialog after finishing some work you can do something like

```
 progress.setMessage("I have a new message now");
```